# Match Date format in string python

Tags: python

I am working on a problem in which I have the **expected string** and matching **input string** with the expected string.

I am matching both the Datetime format as well as the string part of the input.

Example:

Expected String :Ab_xyx_er_2_DD_MM_YYYY

Actual String :Ab_xyx_er_2_12_06_1997

Currently, I am validating the **Actual String** with respect to the **Expected string** by extracting the DD_MM_YYYY and 12_06_1997 if both match then I am matching the string part of both strings then validating that Actual string.

IS there any way to match the Actual string without Slicing in the string in python?

Comment: Could you provide more info? So for your example how is it supposed to match the actual values of the dates with it's format? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the issue with splitting both strings in two an matching them separately. Esp as date is known length and the text bit and date bit have different rules.

You could use this string method.

```py
expected = "abcdef"
actual = "abcdef_01_01_1997"
actual.startswith(expected)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that splitting the string is a problem. But If your **first part** of the string is always the same like input always starts with **Ab_xyx_er_2_** then a trick can be work if you don't want to split the string. You can use **strptime** of **datetime** module

```
from datetime import datetime
# others import


try datetime.strptime(input_string, 'Ab_xyx_er_2_%d_%m_%Y'):
      # Do your work here
except Exception as e:
      print('The string does not match')
      # or do your work
```